# Is there a method to get the URIs from a JENA ARQ Query?

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web, arq

```
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;

public myClass{
    public static void myMethod(Query querySparQL) {

        List<String> A = querySparQL.getGraphURIs();
        List<String> B = querySparQL.getNamedGraphURIs();
        List<Node> C = querySparQL.getResultURIs();

    }
```

Suppose the query looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?ind1 ?ind2 ?ind3 WHERE {
GRAPH <http://Eixample1> {BIND('temporally_harcoded' AS ?XXX) . ?ind1
<http://www.example.com/A#example1> ?ind2 . ?ind2
<http://www.example.com/A#example2> ?ind3 . ?ind1
<http://www.example.com/A#example3> <http://www.example.com/A#example4> .
?ind2 <http://www.example.com/A#example5><http://www.example.com/A#example6> .
<?ind3 <http://www.example.com/A#example7 <http://www.example.com/A#example8> .
 }}
```

I'm looking for a method to get all the URIs: http://www.example.com/A#example1, http://www.example.com/A#example2,....

None of the following methods I've tried contains an URI:

- getGraphURIs()
- getNamedGraphURIs()
- getResultURIs()

Comment: Well, your mentioned methods indeed return particular parts of a SPARQL query as defined in the W3C specs.

Comment: What you need is to apply the static class  `ElementWalker` on the BGP of the graph pattern of the query in combination with an implementation of the `ElementVisitor` interface which in your case collects the URI nodes of each triple pattern.

Comment: Use e.g. Jena's [`QuerySerializer`](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-arq/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/sparql/serializer/QuerySerializer.java) as your guiding example. It has to print all those URIs, among other things.